How to post to facebook page using facebook graph explorer API
I am trying to automate posting to Facebook using the Facebook Node.js SDK. However, for testing purposes, I thought of trying first from the Facebook Graph Explorer API UI. I was following the steps from the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/getting-started/. I added all the permissions but am getting this error when I try posting to https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/page_id/feed. Here is the error:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AvqEpJBCdYALhe1DcGEMOee"
  }
}

Here are the scopes:pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_metadata, pages_manage_posts, public_profile.Idont know where the problem is because i have added all the permission needed.
I expected somrthing like this as per the documentation.
{
"id": "page_post_id"
}

You can´t post to groups with API anymore
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2024/01/23/introducing-facebook-graph-and-marketing-api-v19/
